# Как правильно подключить JQuery плагины в Angular 2?

Tags: jquery, angular

Сделал верстку и собрал проект с помощью gulp, все библиотеки и плагины объеденил в 1 файл. Далее подключил его и скрипты в .angular-cli

```
"scripts": [
"./assets/js/libs.min.js",
"./assets/js/common.js"
]
```

После загрузки страницы все работает, но если делать маршрутизацию в проекте, после перехода по страницам скрипты перестают работать.

Можно ли подобным образом подключать JQuery и плагины? И как заставить их работать?

Comment: Не по теме, но мне одному кажется, что использование angular + jquery - это странно. Может Backbone будет уместнее?

Comment: Можно и так подключать. Думаю у вас при переходе какая та ошибка